# Python processing csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am encountering some weird things here.I am using python's csv module to process csv file.
The example code is below

```
import csv
f = open('file.csv','r')
for i in csv.reader(f):
    print i
```

This prints out all rows as lists and works just fine.And then when I want to do another thing like

```
for i in csv.DictReader(f):
    print i['header']
```

Think this should print all the data with the header called 'header'.It failed.Then I tried a lot.I found I need to run the open file function again each time I run some csv method.It seems redundant to me.Think i might miss some steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're done reading the file the first time, you need to seek back to its beginning to read it again. Something like `f.seek(0,0)`.

Comment: Oh!thanks!Does it means the reader has some point like thing exists?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @honesty1997. File objects remember file offset they last worked with, so if you need to interact with a file multiple times using the same file object (`f` in this example), make sure to reset that location to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks!Does it means that in this case after I looped through the file, the next time I wanted to loop it again and got nothing because that the file object remember that last time I loop through the file and stop at the end of the object?

Comment: You got it @honesty1997.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way to only get the headers.

```
import csv
f = open('file.csv')
csvDictInstance = csv.DictReader(f)
print csvDictInstance.fieldnames
```